# Getting/Setting value from object without source code access

Tags: java, web-services, spring, reflection

I need to change the URL of an object, but I have neither the source code nor any getters and setters for this object. I am able to see the values in the Eclipse debugger, but I don't have any way to modify it.

The variable `port` receives an object (which implements the `DwsSoap` interface) that I do not have the source code to access.

```
DwsSoap port = service.getDwsSoap();
```

There is a field within this object that I want to change called `address`, but I'm not sure how to change it or retrieve it.

[image: Debugger screenshot]

In order to access `address`, I need to access first the `h` field (shown in the image above). This is how I tried to do it:

```
Object h = PropertyUtils.getProperty(port, "h");
```

But I get a `NoSuchMethodException`:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'h'
```

Is there a way that I can access and change `address` on this variable?

Comment: Although you have the option to use reflection to change the field directly (someone has already given such answer), you have to be aware that this is probably not a preferrable way to achieve what you want unless you are really sure what you are doing.  If they are not giving you setter etc, that may probably because it is not appropriate to change the field.  Changing it manually may break the internal consistency of data of that obj instance, and may cause unpredictable problems.

Comment: Thanks for posting actual image mill...at my current rep level all it would allow is for me to post a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the endpoint address for the wsdl through java like this:

```
String sharePointDWSLocation = spDir + "_vti_bin/Dws.asmx"
DwsSoap port = service.getDwsSoap();
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(
    BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, sharePointDWSLocation)
```

Comment: Makes me smile that the question *"How to hack object via reflection?"* was really just *"How can I programatically change jax-ws port endpoint URL?"*.

Comment: My apologies Pavel - I'm pretty new to web services. I figured there was probably some better way of pinpointing what I was actually trying to do. I just described my problem in the best manner I understood at the time. Thanks for your input though, I'll try to do better in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "raw" reflection, not Spring's `PropertyUtils`. It's [covered in the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html). The code will (modulo exception handling) look kind of like this:

```
DwsSoap port = ...;
Field hField = port.getClass().getField("h");
hField.setAccessible(true); // the field will probably be private
Object h = hField.get(port);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to get this working due to the fact that the port.getClass() method returned an object with nearly all of it's properties set to null. The field "h" did not exist, which is strange because it can be clearly seen in the screenshot I had above. Something was apparently very odd about the object that was returned from the web service. I did end up finding a solution to this posted below. Thank you for posting this answer though - this seems like a pretty neat solution.